# Implementing ROPC based authentication in asp .net core

Tags: asp.net, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to implement ROPC flow in asp.net  api . Can you please guide me on how to achieve this properly in ASP.net core using built in authentication library. If it is not possible what are the alternatives

I'm able to get the access token using http call to azure AD token endpoint. But i'm not able to validate the token using built in authentication library
can we implement this without the HTTP call , but using built in library.

`services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));`

Im using the below code snippet to get the access token

```
 private async Task<string> GetTokenAsync(string username, string password)
    {
        string grantType = "password";
        string tenantId = Configuration["AzureAdNative:TenantId"];
        string clientId = Configuration["AzureAdNative:ClientId"];
        string resource = Configuration["AzureAdNative:Resource"];


        string endpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId + "/oauth2/token";


        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();


        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));


        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dict.Add("grant_type", grantType);
        dict.Add("client_id", clientId);
        dict.Add("username", username);
        dict.Add("password", password);
        dict.Add("resource", resource);

        var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, endpoint) { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict) };
        var res = await client.SendAsync(req);
        string result = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var jwt = JObject.Parse(result);

        return result;
       // return jwt.GetValue("access_token").ToString();
    }
```

getting unauthorised 401 error while validating with above code. access token is being sent in the authorization header (eg: Authorization : Bearer e4dgkddskdsdk).

Comment: Why are you using ROPC flow? Did you know it doesn't work if a user has MFA for example?

Comment: Yes , I'm aware of the fact that this flow doesn't support MFA. But this is needed for some internal application.

Comment: Okay, make sure you have requested the token for the correct resource / with correct scopes. If you could add some of that code here that would help.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code snippet for getting the access token

Comment: What's your Resource? It should be the client id or app id URI of the API's app in Azure AD

Comment: Thanks a lot . My resource Id was wrong , now the authentication is working. 
Is there any alternate way to use the ROPC method without making the HTTP call by ourselves (using .net authentication library). This is because I don't want to handle refresh tokens and expiry time my self.

Comment: Not sure, I know ADAL.net removed the overload for ROPC quite some time ago.